# RVM is removing /usr/bin from my PATH

Tags: ruby, path, rvm

Help?

I just recently uninstalled rvm:

```
rvm implode
```

then reinstalled it:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Unfortunately, now when I try to run most (not all) rvm commands, it removes /usr/bin from my PATH and so can't find all the command-line commands it needs, like grep, sed, etc. I've included below an unedited copy and paste of my console:

```
[~]$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/Thai/.rvm/bin
[~]$ rvm use
Now using system ruby.
[~]$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Developer/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/Thai/.rvm/bin
[~]$
```

The same thing happens with `rvm install...` and `rvm remove...` but not `rvm help` or `rvm info`.

Any ideas on what's going on? the `rvm install...` fails after compiling because it needs to access the command-line utils in /usr/bin

Comment: This is on-topic: RVM is a programmer specific tool used to control the Ruby execution environment.  The FAQ allows questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: not related: noticed that you have several `/usr/bin` in the original path

Comment: Can you paste your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`? Are you on Linux, OS X, BSD...?
I think this might be related to your environment and how RVM modified your configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your bin path in your .bash_profile

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/environment for the system wide path.

My guess is that RVM is overriding the path somewhere, and rvm implode is failing to remove the offending script because the PATH is missing /usr/bin.  Try adding the path manually and running rvm implode.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when RVM tries to cleanup the `PATH` from all occurrences of `rvm`, basically it means you have a very old system installation that had `/usr/bin/rvm` - just remove it:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/rvm
```